# Proportions using prop.table

Tags: r, proportions

I'm working on an assignment and wanted to double check to ensure I performed this code correctly. The question asked: What proportion of female infants were born by abdominal method of delivery?

```
table(SB_xlsx$sex)
## 
## female   male 
##    320    330
table(SB_xlsx$delivery)
## 
## abdominal   vaginal 
##       314       335
prop.table(table(SB_xlsx$sex, SB_xlsx$delivery))
##         
##          abdominal   vaginal
##   female 0.2426584 0.2503864
##   male   0.2395672 0.2673879
```

Have I done this correctly to say the proportion of female infants that were born through abdominal means is 0.24? I wanted to double check!

EDIT: Thank you to those who helped, this was my final solution!

```
library(dplyr)
SB_xlsx <- SB_xlsx %>% filter(sex=="female")
prop.table(table(SB_xlsx$sex, SB_xlsx$delivery))
##         
##          abdominal  vaginal
##   female  0.492163 0.507837
```

Comment: No, you need to subset `SB_xlsx$delivery` over only females and then look at the proportion of `abdominal`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Is there any specific R code you would suggest? I'm still trying to learn R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's partially completed. You can apply a filter before calculating the proportions like this:

```
library(dplyr)

SB_xlsx <- SB_xlsx %>% filter(sex=="female")

prop.table(table(SB_xlsx$sex, SB_xlsx$delivery))
```

Now you make sure that only females are measured.